# Outdoor 3-way motion sensor on a low volt circuit?

Tags: wiring, motion-sensor

50ft path from driveway to front door.
Volt 150w transformer.
5 kichler fixtures, currently daisy chained.
no significant drop.
Want a motion sensor on each end: exactly how does one wire this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your second line looks like it's missing something right there at the beginning, please [edit] and finish your thought. Also some additional detail, like how is the wiring currently run - direct burial or in conduit? Is it a cable or individual wires? 120v or 12/24v low-voltage (maybe that's the part that got left off...)? How is it currently switched?

Comment: Is your transformer 12V or 24V? Is replacing wiring an option?

Answer (score 0):

Even with the great lack of detail in the question as it currently stands, normally to have "a motion sensor at each end" you need new/additional wires running all the way from one end to the other. The motion sensors need power all the time, so you can't have one at the end away from the current power source without running new wiring for that.

Beyond that, hard to say given lack of detail in the question.

Comment: ha!  my apologies.  Professional chef/DIY guy here, don't know the right details!  so- I appreciate your comments and will try to add details here.  If there is any 'obvious' info I'm leaving out, please ask directly and I'll try to provide the data.  Here we go:

Comment: @Mike -- your comment got cut off -- try editing the details into the question?

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need 3 wires between all points.  The lamps are wired to **switched-hot** and **common**.  The sensors are wired to those two and also **always-hot**.